# Writing $\sin(\frac{\pi}{180})$ as a fraction, where I'm wrong?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Yesterday I had the idea that, if $\sin(\frac{\pi}{30})$ for example could be written as a fraction I should be able to write $\sin(\frac{\pi}{180})$ too, so I started writing $\sin(\frac{\pi}{60})$ as a fraction, than i used the formula: $$\sin(3x)=-4\sin^3(x)+3\sin(x)$$
to find $\sin(\frac{\pi}{180})$, so:
$$4\sin^3\left(\frac{\pi}{180}\right)-3\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{180}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{60}\right)=0$$Now, making $\sin(\frac{\pi}{60})=k$, we write the cubic equation:$$4\sin^3\left(\frac{\pi}{180}\right)-3\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{180}\right)+k=0$$By Cardano's method:
$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{180}\right)=\sqrt[3]{\frac{-k}{8}+\sqrt{\left(\frac{-k}{8}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^3}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{-k}{8}-\sqrt{\left(-\frac{k}{8}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^3}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt[3]{-k+\sqrt{k^2+1}}+\sqrt[3]{-k-\sqrt{k^2+1}}\right)$$
We know that $\sqrt{k^2+1}>k$, than we can say that $\sqrt{k^2+1}=S$:
$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt[3]{-k+S}+\sqrt[3]{-k-S}\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt[3]{-k+S}+\sqrt[3]{(k+S)}\sqrt[3]{-1}\right)$$
$\sqrt[3]{-1}=-1$ or $e^{\frac{i\pi}{3}}$ or $e^{\frac{-i\pi}{3}}$.
In this case $e^{\frac{i\pi}{3}}$ should be the right answer because in other case $\sin(\frac{\pi}{180})$ would be negative, but when i calculated the value of all this cases the answer with -1 gives $-\sin(\frac{\pi}{180})$ and the others returned complex numbers, so where did I get something wrong?

Comment: Whoa. Slow down. You mean that $\sin (30^\circ) = \sin (\pi/6)$ is a fraction.  Start over.

Comment: `if sin(π/30) could be written as a fraction` You mean [$\;\sin(\frac{\pi}{30})=\frac{-1 - \sqrt{5} + \sqrt{6 (5 - \sqrt{5})}}{8}\,$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin(+pi+%2F+30+))?

Comment: I think you mean $\sin 30^\circ=\dfrac12$

Comment: $p=-3/4 $ how comes it becomes positive in Cardiano's formula ?

Comment: Maybe of interest http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~cds/articles/trig.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you did anything wrong. It's just that $\sin(\dfrac{\pi}{180})$ and $-\sin(\dfrac{\pi}{180})$, satisfies the same equation and the Cardano's formula happens to give the latter.